# I am not able to set default value of textbox using php while using angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs

I am not able to set default value of textbox using php while using angularjs

```
<input type="text" ng-model="formToken" value="<?php echo $token; ?>">
```

In this the output is not showing token value in textbox, but when I remove ng-model="formToken" then token value showing in value attribute, otherwise its showing blank.
I want to pass $token to textbox value attribute, how can I fix this?

Comment: Sounds like something in Angular $scope must be overriding this.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you're binding the value of the input to `formToken`, which is likely not set. Setting `value` will not set the value on the scope (because of how angular parses the DOM).

To set the value through PHP, you could use the `ng-init` attribute:

```
<input type="text" 
       ng-model="formToken" 
       ng-init="formtoken = '<?php echo $token; ?>'">
```

Alternatively, you could set the value in your controller using

```
scope.formToken = whateverYouLike;
```